# Cocoa framework import: is it necessary in headers if it's in your pch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

As per the title, I'm interested in whether it's good or bad practice to remove `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` from your class headers if the same import is included in your pre-compiled header (`.pch`).

Apple's boilerplate classes include the import, but the default project setup in Xcode also imports the Cocoa framework into the default pre-compiled header as well.

It seems to me this is a stylistic question, but I'm interested in opinions and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually remove them for files that I know will only be used in the current project. For files that are re-usable (and hence might be used within a project that doesn't have  or  or whatever defined in the PCH), I tend to leave them in.

Answer (score 2):

I still import them because it kinda sets the tone as to what the class does and requires. Especially more so if the class can be shared in other projects.

Otherwise, you're golden.

Answer (score 2):

I still import the framework headers in my files, since – although boilerplate – if the files were ever used elsewhere, explicitly `#import`ing them in the header means that it will still build even if the other project's Prefix.pch doesn't `#import` the framework, for some reason.

For me the more useful question is whether Cocoa.h needs to be included *at all*; if I have a model class that is using only Foundation classes such as `NSString` or `NSArray`, I will leave the Cocoa.h import in my project's Prefix.pch, but will tend to import Foundation.h in the class header as it makes it easier to share between iOS/Mac projects. Even if you don't require it at current, I find it's always good to think ahead, and for me it just feels more semantically correct, if you're not going to use other classes from AppKit or whatever.